# Change color of div when button on another page is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hope you can help me, i have a page named "diagnosticoST", with 4 buttons (btn-institucional, btn-economico, btn-social, btn-natural) those are with  background colors before the survey inside them is completed, and when the user completes the survey (example page) "Quadrant_1" and click the Continue button it returns to the "diagnosticoST" page and has to change the color of the button that was clicked, i cant figure how to storage the clicked button function so that when i return to the first page it changes the color of the button (i cant do it by css because the trigger for the color change has to be the continue button)

Here is the code im using but its not working Please help me :(

```
<!---QUADRANT_1 PAGE -->
<html>
    <button class="quadrant_1">Continue</button>
</html>

<script>
    $(".quadrant_1").on("click",function(){
        localStorage.setItem('quadrant_1', 'clicked');
        window.location.href = "diagnosticoST.html";
    });

</script>

<!---DIAGNOSTICOST PAGE -->
<div class="row">
    <a href="quadrant_1.html">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 number" style="background-color:#003E8B; cursor: pointer;" id="btn-institucional">
            <p>1</p>
            <img src="icons/institucional.png" width= "50%">
            <p>Desarrollo Institucional para un Buen Gobierno</p>   
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
if(localStorage.getItem('quadrant_1') === 'clicked'){
    $("btn-institucional").css({backgroundColor: "red"});
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's very long. Can you edit it down to a more minimal example of your issue?

Comment: Hi! i´ve edited the code to have only de js and html of the button page and the js and html of the first page. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, much more readable. Good example of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the element you want to select is this one:

`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 number" style="background-color:#003E8B; cursor: pointer;" id="btn-institucional">`

Its ID is `btn-institucional`. To select an ID, put `#` in front of the selector string:

`$("#btn-institucional").css({backgroundColor: "red"});`

(your `$("btn-institucional")` searches for an element whose *tag name* is `btn-institucional`, which of course doesn't exist)

If you're trying to communicate between one page and another like that, I'd suggest ditching localStorage and using window.open instead, something like this:

```
const w = window.open('https:// ... surveyToComplete.html');
w.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.querySelector('#submitSurveyButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
    $("btn-institucional").css({backgroundColor: "red"});
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it changes the color when the page loads not when the button "Continue" was clicked on the other page :(

Comment: That's probably because you're using localStorage, which persists across page loads and doesn't get cleared naturally - and you probably already navigated to the other page and clicked the button during testing. Clear your browser's localStorage to test again. Though, it'd probably be better to communicate via something created with window.open() instead.

Comment: When i return from the page that has the button continue after clicking it, the "btn-institucional" doesn´t change it´s color.

Comment: Added stuff to answer - try using window.open instead of localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

clear your local storage on your first page.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


      localStorage.clear();

        $(".quadrant_1").on("click",function(){
            localStorage.setItem('quadrant_1', 'clicked');
            window.location.href = "index2.html";
        });

        if(localStorage.getItem('quadrant_1') === 'clicked'){
        $("#btn-institucional").css({backgroundColor: "red"});
        }
    }

)
```

here is a plunkr.

https://plnkr.co/edit/YiFkmTXIYiGA8XpxkUkK?p=preview

Comment: Hi  my first page is the one that has the div that has to change, so i put  <script>
 

$( document ).ready(function() {
  
     localStorage.clear();

 if(localStorage.getItem('quadrant_1') === 'clicked'){
    $("#btn-institucional").css({backgroundColor: "red"});
    }
     })

 </script> and on the page that contains the button (my page 2) i putted like this <script>

      $(".quadrant_1").on("click",function(){
        localStorage.setItem('quadrant_1', 'clicked');
        window.location.href = "diagnosticoST.html";
    });
    
</script>
 its something wrong?

Comment: im so sorry im learning js thats why i cant understand very well how to do it please help me :(